# Remove interior stickers such as airbag deployment warnings from car

Tags: interior, cleaning

I would like to remove the stickers on my visors that explain about the airbags from my car without damaging the visors. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a hair dryer to heat them up and carefully use a razor blade to get under the edge to start pulling it. Use alcohol to remove any residual adhesive.

Since it is possible that alcohol may damage some fabrics, use cautiously/sparingly at first. Applying alcohol to a rag and using it to wipe is always safer than applying alcohol directly to the fabric.

Comment: Perhaps try something milder than alcohol first? "Goo Gone," perhaps?

Comment: @William Cline: Ooh no. Goo Gone ain't no milder than alcohol. Be sure of that. I've been stung by that in the past. Not that it's a bad product, but alcohol is truly safer.

Comment: Indeed, Goo Gone and similar products will dissolve all sorts of plastics, artificial textile fibers, polyurethane, etc.